# How share data from one app in android wear to app in android mobile?

Tags: android, android-wear-2.0

I have to develop an app for smart watch using android studio, the problem is that i need synchronization the app in the smart watch with one app in a mobile, I mean, I need to create something like apps for check your healt and watch your stadistics in your smartphone, but... I don't know how can I sinchronizate the app in my smart watch with my app in my smartphone, I was searching some tutorial but I didn't found anyting, the problem is not how create the application, the real problem is how sinchronizate the data bwteen smart watch and smarth phone.If someone have any tutorial or any idea how to deal with this.

Comment: Did you see: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/data-layer#send-and-sync-with-API

Comment: @MorrisonChang you saved my life, I mean I was looking in youtube or google some examples but I couldn't found nothing jajajaja I feel like a stupid but thanks man, I'm gonna read the documentation.